# how to reverse char array using class member pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, arrays

im tryin to reverse an array using pointer which is a class member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class my_string
{
    char* ptr;
    int size;
public:
    my_string(){};
    my_string(char* str) : ptr(str),size(strlen(ptr)){};
    char* getstr () {return ptr;};
    void reverse();
    int find (char);
    void print();
};

void my_string::reverse()
{
     int size2=size;
     for (int i=0;i<(size/2);i++)
       {
           char tmp=ptr[i];
           ptr[i]=ptr[size2-1];
           ptr[size2-1]=ptr[i];
           size2--;
       }
}

int my_string::find(char c)
{
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
     {
        if (ptr[i]==c)
        return i;
     }
    return -1;
}

void my_string::print()
{
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<ptr[i];
    cout<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    my_string s1("abcde");
    s1.print(); 
    s1.reverse();
    s1.print();
}
```

im not gettin any errors but the reverse function is surely not working.
can someone please explain to me why?

*this is an homework assignment asking me not to use dynamic allocation or strings (for now).

Comment: you have `size2-1`, i think it should be `size2-i`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention not being able to use standard library algorithms, so

```
std::reverse(ptr, ptr+size);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard algorithm `std::reverse` declared in header `<algorithm>`. 
For example

```
std::reverse( ptr, ptr + size );
```

But if you want to do it yourself then the function could look the following way

```
void my_string::reverse()
{
     for ( int i = 0; i < size/2; i++ )
     {
           char tmp = ptr[i];
           ptr[i] = ptr[size-1-i];
           ptr[size-1-i] = tmp;
     }
}
```

A test program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "123456789";
    char *ptr = s;
    int size = std::strlen( ptr );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size/2; i++ )
    {
              char tmp = ptr[i];
              ptr[i] = ptr[size-1-i];
              ptr[size-1-i] = tmp;
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Output is

```
123456789
987654321
```

Comment: i tried copying the answer u placed but it still doesnt work. i even tried using reverse with the member functions that one of them i just decared now :  `code`   char* getstr () {return ptr;};
 char* getstrsize() {return ptr+size;};`code`

Comment: I can guess that you are using a string literal as an argument of the constructor. You may not use string literals such a way. They may not be changed.

Comment: I think that your class shall dynamically allocate memory and copy  argumentl in this memory. And destructor shall free this memory. Also you need to write a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.